# Google Workspace: manage domain-wide delegation programmatically

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-workspace

I have an application that can manage Google Calendar within the Google Workspace of the company.  The application contains more than one company.
I want to use domain-wide delegation. As described [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/162106#zippy=%2Cset-up-domain-wide-delegation-for-a-client) or [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account) admin of the workspace needs to add service account id and scope manually.

Is the way to do this programmatically?

Answer (score 2):

After some research and also looking into Google Workspace's Admin SDK documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk) and [here](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/admin-settings) this does not seem to be an available option at the moment.

You may want to submit a feature request [here](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/support#missing_features) for that.

Answer (score 0):

For service or local applications, the admin has to manually generate the service account and grant this service account with domain-wide authorization.   There is no way to do this programmatically (unless for pure SaaS applications).

Comment: what did you mean by "unless for pure SaaS applications"?

Comment: @YoavFeuerstein. Google allows SaaS applications to manage domain-wide delegation programmatically.

Comment: Where/how is that possible? I searched through their documentation but couldn't find any SDK function related to domain-wide delegation

Comment: @YoavFeuerstein you need to use oauth2 service accounts https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#serviceaccount 

I haven't done it yet but came across your comment during my research ... the info on the Control API might also be of interest as a starting point https://support.google.com/a/answer/162106?hl=en

Comment: @rorykoehler Thanks, but from what I understand these links only tells us about how to *manually* grant domain-wide delegation to a service, which only then can be used programmatically to whatever you want it to do. My goal is to *programmatically* let the user to approve DWD from their GWS account to my app or service account - without requiring the user to go through any manual steps - just like when they approve an app's access to their account(s) with a single page a few clicks.

Comment: @YoavFeuerstein from what I understand installing via Workspace Marketplace automatically generates the service account, otherwise the install has to be done manually by an admin. I haven't implemented it yet though so I'll try remember to provide an update here once I do.